# Writing generalized save and read

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I want to write a class for both reading and writing objects from/to file. I use the template keyword to achive this aim.

```
 template<class T>
 class A{
  private:
   std::string filePath;//This will use to indicate the path of proper file.
  public:
    void save(T a){
     //write the given object to the file. The path is fetched by filePath
    }
    std::list<T> read(){
    //read the file and put each line in the list. The path is fetched by filePath
    }
    A(std::string path):filePath(path){}
 };
```

If I use this method, everything is fine when I used it with primitive types like, int, or float. But the problem arise when I want to work with object, e.g, Circle,Rectacngle.
What should I do to solve the problem

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? What kind of objects? Do you have a root class in your hierarchy? Why (what for) do you want to input and output them?

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple engine for storing and retrieving data in file. So I try to use template to generalized the situation. I don't know the objects or the fields of objects.

Comment: If you need a fully generic solution, it is not possible in portable C++... You need some C++ code generator. And it won't be simple.

Comment: Why do you need a generic simple engine? Did you consider using some application checkpointing library?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (or perhaps even [persistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), e.g. [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing)...). Sometimes it is called *data pickling*.

You could use the [s11n](http://s11n.net/) library (giving templates for serializing C++ data).

You could also define your `operator <<` and `operator >>` on your own classes, so with your `Rectangle r;` you would code `std::cout << r;` and `std::cin >> r;`

You could consider textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (or YAML or XML...) e.g. using [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)

Serializing arbitrary graphs is much more difficult that serializing tree-like data structures (because of [circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) and shared pointers....).

There is no simple automatic way to get serialization facilities in C++, and you probably don't want one. Imagine that you are representing human marriages between `Person`-s in some of your class. For efficiency reasons you may want to have *two* tables (of type `std::map<(Person,Person>`), one mapping wife to every husband and another mapping husband to every wife (you want both tables because you often query the husband of some woman, or the wife of some man). But you probably don't want to serialize both of these tables (they are somehow "redundant"), just a set of husband+wife pairs. This is to illustrate that serialization is often *application specific*.