# please help write structure into binary file

Tags: c

I am new in C. I am trying to create a C program as a simple ticket system for practise.

I want to write the structure into a binary file then read it. but it is not writing anything into the binary file.

What I got is only

> File successfully closed.
>
> File successfully closed.

The binary file (ticket.bin) is still empty.

If anyone could type an example to help me to understand how to write structure into binary file and read it.

```
define STATIONNUM 10//Maximun number of station.

define rate1 160

define rate2 190

define rate3 230

struct Ticket{

    int code;//code of the list
    char station[20];//destination name.
    int price;//transportation fee.
};



int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    int c;//for open close judgement return value.
    int i;//use at for loop.
    
    struct Ticket list[STATIONNUM]={
    {1, "NewYork", rate1},
    {2, "London", rate1},
    {3, "Paris", rate1},
    {4, "Tokyo", rate1},
    {5, "HongKong　", rate2},
    {6, "Sydney", rate2},
    {7, "Milan", rate2},
    {8, "Berlin", rate2},
    {9, "Vancouver", rate3},
    {10, "Afghanistan", rate3},
    };

    //open a binary file to write.
    fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "wb");
    if(! fp){
        printf("open file fail");
    }
    
    //write data into binary file.
   if (fwrite(list, sizeof(list[0]), STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM);

    //close it.
    c = fclose(fp);
    
    //judge if it's closed.
    if(c == -1){
        printf("File close failed.\n");
    }else if(c == 0){
        printf("File successfully closed.\n");
    }

    //open binary file to read.
    fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "rb");
    if(! fp){
        printf("open file fail");
    }
    
    fread(list, sizeof(struct Ticket), STATIONNUM, fp);
    
    //close it.
    c = fclose(fp);
    
    //judge if it's closed.
    if(c == -1){
        printf("File close failed.\n");
    }else if(c == 0){
        printf("File successfully closed.\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this `C#` or `C++`?

Comment: Looks more like C (fopen/printf), though all of that can be used in c++.

Comment: Additionally, you should probably exit the program if the file open fails, rather than just printing out an error message and continuing.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19067084/841108) to a related question. I don't recommend writing *binary* files these days. Consider instead either some serialization into a textual format (JSON, YAML...), or using some database... (MariaDB, PostGresql, MongoDB...)

Comment: @user2813862 from where did you get the idea that `int` is 10 bytes long? It most probably isn't. That's not how stuff works. That entire horrible loop can be replaced by `if (fwrite(list, sizeof list[0], STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM)` if you don't need platform-independence.

Comment: would anyone give me a example to write structure into binary correctly? i wanna know where went wrong. i search all over the website and still couldn't understand.

Comment: *Carefully* read [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) man page (and read it several times).

Comment: You're also trying to fprintf() in a file opened in read-binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
if (fwrite(list, sizeof(list[0]), STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM);
```

should at least be

```
if (fwrite(list, sizeof(struct Ticket), 
           STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM)
  { perror("fwrite"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and you may consider doing `if (fflush(fp)) perror("fflush");` after that.

and you obviously forgot

```
if fread(list, sizeof(struct Ticket), 
           STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM)
  { perror("fread"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

after the successful `fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "rb");` line.

You are right in testing every library call like `fopen` & `fread` but on failure you should display with `perror` the error reason (or use `strerror(errno)`).

Your code

```
 fprintf(fp, "%d\t%s\t%d\n", 
         list[i].code, list[i].station, list[i].price);
```

has no sense. (You should test that the result of that `fprintf` is 3, or else `perror`). You are printing text in a `fp` handle opened for binary read!
Perhaps you just want `printf` here.

BTW, calling `list` a variable which is in fact an array is utterly confusing...

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
also thanks for all comment.
would you explain what is 
{ perror("fread"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
i never seen perror also is EXIT_FAILURE a function?

Once again Thanks a lot

Comment: Take time to read a good C programming book, and perhaps also a system programming book (on Linux that might be http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ...). I don't have many hours to spend teaching you C & system programming. Also compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Thanks i used the code that you provided but it is still not writing anything into binary file. the ticket.bin is still empty.
Thanks for your time. and sorry for bad coding.

Comment: It is really time to spend some hours reading books, and learning about debugging (and how to use your debugger). Also, it would be helpful if you said which operating system, compiler, and compilation command you are using.

Comment: window 7 with Tera Term and compiler named UnEditor
atm, i would really wanna see how to successfully write structure into binary file.

Comment: UnEditor is probably not a compiler, just an editor (or some IDE). And you need to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: sadly, i have no idea what is debugger.
If i fail to write structure into binary,
i have been told couldn't go any further.
that's why i am so desperatly need help.

Comment: I can't help anymore. You need to learn how to use a debugger. Yes, that take hours.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that problems are here:

(1)

```
  ...
  //open a binary file to write.
      fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "wb");  
                                 |
                                 v
     ///...fopen("ticket.bin", "w" ); /// 
  ...
```

(2)

```
  ...
    //write data into binary file.
      if (fwrite(list, sizeof(list[0]), STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM);
                 |
                 v
    ///...fwrite(&list,...  /// 
  ...
```

Follow by this example and try to change your code step by step:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STATIONNUM 10 //Maximun number of station.

#define rate1 160
#define rate2 190
#define rate3 230

struct Ticket
{
  int  code;//code of the list
  char station[20];//destination name.
  int  price;//transportation fee.
};

int main()
{ FILE *fp;
  int i; //use at for loop.
  struct Ticket list[STATIONNUM] =
  {
    {  1, "NewYork      ", rate1 },
    {  2, "London       ", rate1 },
    {  3, "Paris        ", rate1 },
    {  4, "Tokyo        ", rate1 },
    {  5, "HongKong     ", rate2 },
    {  6, "Sydney       ", rate2 },
    {  7, "Milan        ", rate2 },
    {  8, "Berlin       ", rate2 },
    {  9, "Vancouver    ", rate3 },
    { 10, "Afghanistan  ", rate3 },
  };

  // open a binary file to write; write it; and close ///
  if (!(fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "w"))) { printf("open file fail"); }
  if (fwrite(&list, sizeof(list[0]), STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM);
  if ((fclose(fp))==-1) { printf("File close failed.\n"); }

  // 1-st
  // open binary file to read; read; and close it ///
  if (!(fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "r"))) { printf("open file fail"); }
  fread(&list, sizeof(struct Ticket), STATIONNUM, fp);
  if ((fclose(fp))==-1) { printf("File close failed.\n"); }

  // Display initial information
  for (i=0;i<STATIONNUM;i++)
      { printf("%3d %s %d \n", list[i].code, list[i].station, list[i].price); }
  getchar();

  // Change some thing :) ///
  list[0].code = 20;  strcpy(list[0].station, "MOSKOW       "); list[0].price = 200;
  list[1].code = 30;  strcpy(list[1].station, "MINSK        "); list[1].price = 250;
  list[8].code = 60;  strcpy(list[8].station, "ALMATY       "); list[8].price = 330;
  list[9].code = 90;  strcpy(list[9].station, "VLADIVOSTOK  "); list[9].price = 530;

  // open a binary file to write; write it; close the file ///
  if (!(fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "w"))) { printf("open file fail"); }
  if (fwrite(&list, sizeof(list[0]), STATIONNUM, fp) != STATIONNUM);
  if ((fclose(fp))==-1) { printf("File close failed.\n"); }

  // 2-nd
  // open binary file to read; read; and close it ///
  if (!(fp = fopen("ticket.bin", "r"))) { printf("open file fail"); }
  fread(&list, sizeof(struct Ticket), STATIONNUM, fp);
  if ((fclose(fp))==-1) { printf("File close failed.\n"); }

  // Display new information again
  for (i=0;i<STATIONNUM;i++)
      { printf("%3d %s %d \n", list[i].code, list[i].station, list[i].price); }
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Good luck!